# Colorbox background not disappearing after I close color

Tags: jquery, colorbox, background-color

I have a form that is displayed in a colorbox when I click on a link. When I click on the link a semi-trasparent background is displayed. When I click on the x image on the colorbox, my form disappears and the background also vanishes. However when I click on the link the second time, an opaque background is displayed. When I click on the close button, my form disappears but the opaque background remains.

I am calling my colorbox  like this :

```
$('a.edit-writer').colorbox({
         width:"800px",
         height: "480px",
         onComplete: function() {
             $('#save-writer').click(function() {
                 saveWriter(this);
                 return false;
             });
         }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you could add a fiddle to show us your problem